# If Soy Milk gets congealed at the bottom, is this a sign that it's going bad?

Tags: soymilk

It happens a lot with vanilla flavored soy milk - the congealed portions sit at the bottom of the container and looks like whip cream - does this mean that it's going bad?

Answer (score 12):

That sounds like the settling of the soy solids at the bottom of the carton; shaking the milk before pouring it should solve that issue.